# rails_admin, callbacks don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

i'm using rails_admin
i have three models (Poll) (MobileUser) (MobileUserPoll)

```
class Poll <  ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :mobile_users_polls
has_and_belongs_to_many :mobile_users , :join_table => :mobile_users_polls

class MobileUsersPoll < ActiveRecord::Base
after_save :send_notifications
```

when creating a poll and choosing mobile users (using multiselect provided by rails_admin) the MobileUsersPoll records are being created automatically,
the problem is the (after_save) callback is don't work
anyone have any idea?

thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors / warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Rails website:

"You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model."

Therefore, change the association setup to a `has_many :through` association. See here for further info:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association